# I got incorrect labels on my X-Axis on a Seaborn Table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

```
#counts of all people questioned of their respective category
category = ['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'loan', 'contact', 'day', 'month', 'poutcome','y']
#iterates through all columns and relevant categories 
for column in category:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    sns.barplot(df[column].value_counts().values, df[column].value_counts().index)
    plt.xticks(rotation=25)
    plt.title(column)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

So the first loop I have here is just for showing how many people are in the respective category the output is right for my purpouse and looks like this:
[image]

so far so good...

But then I wanted to have a stacked Barplot where I show how many people of each category bought a certain Product,  the values seem to be correct, but the labeling is off for some reason and I wonder why...

```
category = ['job', 'marital', 'education', 'loan']

#iterates through all columns and relevant categories 
for column in category:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    #counts the individual value occurence of each row for each respective category
    df.positives = df.loc[df.y.values == 'yes', column].value_counts() 
    df.negatives = df.loc[df.y.values == 'no', column].value_counts()
    print(df.positives)
    
    df.combinedEachCategory = df.positives + df.negatives
    #print(df.combinedEachCategory)

    df.allCounts = list(set(list(df.positives.index) + list(df.negatives.index)))

    ax = sns.barplot(df.positives, df.combinedEachCategory)
    overlay = sns.barplot(x = df.combinedEachCategory, y = df.positives, color = "#0000A3")
    ax.set_xticklabels(df.positives.index)
    plt.xticks(rotation=25)
    plt.title(column)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

here is my output from the code above, as you can see the values seem to accurate but the labeling is completely wrong.

[image]

data: [.csv](https://gofile.io/d/05Vet0) on Gofile

Comment: If you present the data, you may get a faster answer.

Comment: added the csv. File

Comment: I requested permissions to see the contents of the file, but that doesn't mean that anyone can't get the data to I cannot respond to the answer by reference. Let's fix it so that everyone can refer to it. Also, I checked the contents of the file and it's not in CSV format, it's all in the cells in column A. It is.

Comment: Also, please delete the email request from me. I'll delete your permission mail too.

Comment: Now I think this downloadlink should work  https://gofile.io/d/05Vet0